# how to get id of event.target from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, events, target

For example:

```js
function helloworld(){
    alert("helloworld");
}

function worldhello(){
    alert("worldhello");
}
```

Two function and three buttons.

Clicking the *'A'* button will execute the `helloworld()` function.

Clicking the *'B'* button will execute the `worldhello()` function.

When you click on the *'C'* button, the `helloworld ()` function is executed and the `worldhello ()` function is executed.

I want to prevent the alert of the `helloworld()` function from being executed when the *'C'* button is clicked.

I tried to use `event.target.id` and `$(event.target).attr("id")` to find the `id` of the *'C'* button in the `helloworld()` function, but it printed `undefined`.

How do I find the `id` of the *'C'* button in the `helloworld ()` function?

Comment: `I tried to use` Can you post this code you've tried so we can try to debug it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance this code is sample..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what are you going to do after getting the ID of the element, Anyways, There's more generic way to do this. You can pass flags to your functions on whether to show the alert or not.

Try this:

```html
<button onclick="hw(true)">A</button>
<button onclick="wh(true)">B</button>
<button onclick="hw(false); wh(true)">C</button>

<script>
  let hw = shouldAlert => {
    if (shouldAlert) {
      alert("Hello World!");
    }
  };

  let wh = shouldAlert => {
    if (shouldAlert) {
      alert("World Hello!");
    }
  };
</script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should avoid inline handlers - it's basically the same as `eval`, and is very bad practice. Attach listeners with Javascript instead. Also, when a variable isn't going to be reassigned, it should be declared with `const` rather than `let`. `let` tells readers of your code that you're going to reassign the variable in question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for the tips. Apart from readability, is there any other point in using const instead of let?

Comment: No, but readability is often the most important factor to consider when writing maintainable code, especially in larger applications. For the same reason, you see people nowadays using `map` and `reduce` and `filter` and so on instead of using `for` loops, even though `for` loops are faster - because the Array methods are more readable.